# Order a column in mysql by if it contains a letter

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by, columnsorting

I have a column named `convoys` in my worker-database and I first want to sort the 'non-letter-containing'-values and after them the 'letter-containing' ones.

For example here are a few values

| name | convoy |
| --- | --- |
| worker1 | 1 |
| worker2 | 3 |
| worker3 | M 4 |
| worker4 | M5 |
| worker5 | 4 |
| worker6 | 11 |

and it should sort them like this

| name | convoy |
| --- | --- |
| worker1 | 1 |
| worker2 | 3 |
| worker5 | 4 |
| worker6 | 11 |
| worker3 | M 4 |
| worker4 | M5 |

Has anybody some kind of idea how to make this query working?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most direct way to do that would be the following (using regular expression):

```
SELECT name,
       convoy
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY CASE WHEN convoy REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN convoy ELSE convoy END
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by the first token combined from characters that are not digits or spaces, and then by the first token combined from digits (and converted to UNSIGNED).
Please note that this solution also order correctly strings such as 'M13' (which comes after 'M 4' and 'M5')

```
select   *
from     t
order by regexp_substr(convoy, '[^\\d\\s]+')
        ,cast(regexp_substr(convoy, '\\d+') as UNSIGNED)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b649675354c7b4b449f8dfd7132cf0db)

Answer (score -1):

A maximal unsigned integer: [4294967295](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

MySQL 5.6

This SQL sorts 'non-letter-containing' values as numbers, then others.

```
select
 name,
 convoy
from Table1
order by
 case when
   convoy REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
  then convert(convoy, UNSIGNED INTEGER)
  else 4294967295
  end,
convoy
;
```

Or maybe better:

```
select
  *
from Table1
order by
 case when
   convoy REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
  then LPAD(convert(convoy, UNSIGNED INTEGER),10,0)
  else convoy
  end
;
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`name` varchar(7), `convoy` varchar(3))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`name`, `convoy`)
VALUES
    ('worker1', '1'),
    ('worker2', '3'),
    ('worker3', 'M 4'),
    ('worker4', 'M5'),
    ('worker5', '4'),
    ('worker6', '11')
;
```

Output:

| name | convoy |
| --- | --- |
| worker1 | 1 |
| worker2 | 3 |
| worker5 | 4 |
| worker6 | 11 |
| worker3 | M 4 |
| worker4 | M5 |